# Change elements in one list based on elements of another list

Tags: python

I have two lists. The first list is a list of words which represent sentences:

```
x = ['i', 'can', 'tell', 'you', 'about', 'the', 'keynote.', 'help', 'you', 'browse', 'sessions.', 'or', 'recommend', 'specific', 'office', 'hours', 'and', 'app', 'reviews.', 'which', 'would', 'you', 'like?']
```

Second list has the same length as first list and consists of numbers (0, 1, 2, 3 or 4):

```
y = ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0']
```

I need to separate the first and second lists with respect to punctuation marks in the first list. It will look like:

```
x1 = ['i', 'can', 'tell', 'you', 'about', 'the', 'keynote.']
y1 = ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0']

x2 = ['help', 'you', 'browse', 'sessions.']
y2 = ['0', '0', '0', '0']

x3 = ['or', 'recommend', 'specific', 'office', 'hours', 'and', 'app', 'reviews.']
y3 = ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']

x4 = ['which', 'would', 'you', 'like?']
x5 = ['0', '3', '0', '0']
```

From these lists, I need to create two lists. In the new first list, elements will be sentences and in the second new list, elements will be numbers. If a list with numbers has any number other then 0 put it a number in second new list else put zero. It will look like:

```
x_new = ["i can tell you about the keynote.", "help you browse sessions.", "or recommend specific office hours and app reviews.", "which would you like?"]
y_new = [2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Note: if a list with numbers (e.g *y1*) has more than one different number (e.g. *['0', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '0']* then take number that has more concurrence (in this example it is *'1'*). If concurrence of numbers is the same (*['0', '2', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0']*) take first nonzero number in the list (in this example it is *'2'*).

It is my code:

```
x = ['i', 'can', 'tell', 'you', 'about', 'the', 'keynote.', 'help', 'you', 'browse', 'sessions.', 'or', 'recommend', 'specific', 'office', 'hours', 'and', 'app', 'reviews.', 'which', 'would', 'you', 'like?']
y = ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0']
x_new = []
y_new = []
i = 0
k = 0
punctuation_marks = ('.', '?', '!')

# searching punctuation marks
while i < len(x):
    for k in range(i, len(x)):
        # if a punctuation mark has found
        if x[k].endswith(punctuation_marks):
            # create list's element for a sentence 
            x_new += x[i:k]
            # cheaking for promises before the punctuation mark
            for l in range(i, k):
                if y[l] == '1':
                    y_new += '1'
                    break
                else:
                    y += '0'
                    break                 
        break
    i = k
```

But it goes to infinite loop I cannot figure out what wrong with it. Also, I don't know how to count concurrence of numbers in the script (see the note above). My code just finds the first element in the list of numbers.

Comment: As k and i are indices (starting from zero), they will reach no more than len(x)-1. So the while condition will always be True and so never end

Answer (score 0):

If you check start point, then your code will be more efficient.

Try this code.

```
x = ['i', 'can', 'tell', 'you', 'about', 'the', 'keynote.', 'help', 'you', 'browse', 'sessions.', 'or', 'recommend', 'specific', 'office', 'hours', 'and', 'app', 'reviews.', 'which', 'would', 'you', 'like?']
y = ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0']
x_new = []
y_new = []
punctuation_marks = ('.', '?', '!')

s = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].endswith(punctuation_marks):
        x_new.append(' '.join(x[s:i+1]))
        y_new.append(max(list(map(int, y[s:i+1]))))
        s = i + 1
```